# Evaluate double integral of $e^{-x}$ in $S = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : 0 < |y| < x^2 \}$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, exponential-function, multiple-integral

I am working on a Calculus IV problem and just want to check if my argument is accurate ? Sorry if the question seems basic but I am self-studying Multiple Integral at the moment and would really appreciate any feedback.

$$\iint_S e^{-x}dxdy\quad \text{ where }\; S = \left\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : 0 < |y| < x^2 \right\}$$

*Attempted Solution:*

**Notice** $|y| < x^2 \iff -x^2 < y < x^2$, the area of integration is "sandwiched" between $-x^2$ and $x^2$. Because of symmetry, we have, $$\iint_S e^{-x}dxdy = 2\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_0^{x^2} e^{-x} dy dx = 4$$ (After two steps of integration by parts).

Comment: $0<|y|<x^2\Rightarrow y\in (-x^2,0)\cup (0,x^2)$

Comment: I do no think that $e^{-y}$ is symmetric around $0$.

Comment: I guess $x>0$ .... otherwise it is just infinity

Comment: I downvoted since there is a lot of typo. Please notify me when those problems are gone.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int\int_S e^{-x}dxdy=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x}\Big(\int_{-x^2}^{x^2}dy\Big)dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}2x^2e^{-x}dx$$

This integral is $+\infty$ since $\Big(\int_{-\infty}^{-1}+\int_{1}^{\infty}\Big)e^{-x}dx$ is $+\infty$

If you give extra condition $x>0$, then this integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}2x^2e^{-x}dx=2\Gamma(3)=2\times2!=4$.

Then $\int\int_S e^{-x}dxdy=4$

**Note:** $e^{-x}$ is not *symmetric about $0$ function*. $e^{-|x|}$ is.

$$\int\int_S e^{-|x|}dxdy=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-|x|}\Big(\int_{-x^2}^{x^2}dy\Big)dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}2x^2e^{-|x|}dx\\=2\cdot 2 \int_{0}^{\infty}x^2e^{-|x|}dx=4\cdot\Gamma(3)=8$$